# Leaflet map and bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, leaflet

Please have a look at http://www.bootply.com/133473.

I have at least a couple of problems and I didn't find any solution up to now...

First problem: 
The leaflet map is 0px height and the next row is not in the correct position.

Second problem (but maybe it is related to the first one): 
On a small device the width of the map is the full width but I'd like to have a margin and I wasn't able to get it (I tried but margin-left, margin-right and padding-left, padding-right...) and of course the text row is superimposed to the map and that's not what I want...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your [bootply posting](http://www.bootply.com/133473), it looks like your first problem was solved (I see the map so the height must not be 0px).

As for your second problem, it is the Bootstrap Editor that is not able to show your app on smaller screens.  This problem may go away when you view your app on its own web page.

Comment: You can see the app on smaller screens using the preview icons on the upper-right corner of the HTML editor us use http://www.bootply.com/render/133473